# @override a method, Google Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, inheritance, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

I'm trying to override a method of a superclass and compile the code using Google Closure Compiler but I'm getting a warning about wrong types.

```
/Users/Jan/dev/cro/public/app/js/LibraryController.js:55: WARNING -
  mismatch of the setState property type and the type of the property it overrides
  from superclass app.Controller
original: function (this:app.Controller, Object): undefined
override: function (this:app.LibraryController, Object, string, string): undefined
app.LibraryController.prototype.setState = function (state, section, article) {
```

As you can see, I'm not changing the type of the argument accepted by the super method nor do I change the returned type.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? thanks.

To clarify, here are the definitions of the individual methods.

```
/**
 * @param {!Object} state The new state.
 */
app.Controller.prototype.setState = function (state) { ... };

/**
 * @param {!Object} state The new state.
 * @param {string} section A section ID.
 * @param {string} article An article ID.
 * @override
 */
app.LibraryController.prototype.setState = function (state, section, article) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overridden methods must have the same (or at least very similar) signatures. Specifically, Subclass methods must be able to be used anywhere the base class could be used. See a full discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/closure-compiler-discuss/o_CMZAvFOLU/discussion

The error message you post above shows that the overriding method has more **required** arguments than the original which is specifically not allowed. You could however have more **optional** arguments.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that "Subclasses have to be substitutable for the base class, that is, you need to be able to use the subclass anywhere the base class could be used.". If I **make the added arguments optional**, everything is OK ;)

Comment: Correct - I wrote that from memory. I'll update the answer to be a bit more accurate/complete.

Comment: I really like this article: http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/06/subtyping-functions-without-poking-your.html